# Proving that a weighted Sobolev space is a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Consider $N = n+ k$ and in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and also take the variable $(x,y)$. In the article https://doi.org/10.1017/prm.2022.43
is defined for $\gamma \geq 0$ the space
$$
H^{1,2}_{\gamma}(\mathbb{R}^N) = \{u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N): \partial_{x_i}u,|x|^{\gamma}\partial_{y_i}u  \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)\},
$$
and it is said that it is a Hilbert space with the norm
$$
\|u\|^2 = \|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)}^2 +\sum_{i=1}^{n} \|\partial_{x_i}u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)}^2 +\sum_{i=1}^{k} \||x|^{\gamma}\partial_{y_i}u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)}^2.
$$
How to prove it? I could prove it, but with some restriction on $\gamma$, which doesn't seem to be necessary.

The proof of this fact can be seem in Tri, Nguyen Minh. Sobolev imbedding theorems for degenerate metrics. International Centre for Theoretical Physics, 1995. , theorem 4. However I can not understand all the proof. Let me put here the ideia. Taking $u_n$ a Cauchy sequence in $H^{1,2}_\gamma(\mathbb{R}^N)$, one can see that $u_n, \partial_{x_i} u_n$ and $|x|^\gamma \partial_{y_j} u_n$ are Cauchy sequences in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Let $u, v_i, w_j$ the limits in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ of $u_n, \partial_{x_i} u_n$ and $|x|^\gamma \partial_{y_j} u_n$ respectively. I know how to prove that $u$ has $x_i-$ weak derivate and $\partial_{x_i} u = v_i$. Now given $\varphi \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^N)$, notice that
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} (|x|^\gamma u) \partial_{y_i} \varphi dz & = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} (|x|^\gamma u_n) \partial_{y_i} \varphi dz  \\
& = - \lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \partial_{y_i}  (|x|^\gamma u_n) \varphi dz \\
&= - \lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |x|^\gamma \partial_{y_i}(u_n) \varphi dz \\
& = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} w_j \varphi dz.
\end{align}
This shows $|x|^\gamma u$ has $y_j-$weak derivative and $\partial_{y_j} (|x|^\gamma \partial_{y_j} u) = w_j$. Now I would like to use a product rule to show that $\partial_{y_j} (|x|^\gamma \partial_{y_j} u)  = |x|^\gamma \partial_{y_j} u$. I dont't know how guarantee the function $u$ has $y_j-$weak derivative. I suspect it has to be $\frac{w_j}{|x|^\gamma}$. In this case, how to proove that  $\frac{w_j}{|x|^\gamma} \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ for all $\gamma > 0$?

Here is the proof from the cited book(in dimension 2):[image]

Comment: Can you put the full proof from the book word for word or image?

Comment: I just put the proof from the book.

Comment: Why the derivative in $|x|^{\gamma}\partial_{y_{i}}u_{n}$ is $y_{i}$, not $x_{i}$?

Comment: The Euclician space is decomposed in $\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^k$. The term $ \partial_{y_i} u$ is referred to $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: @NeymarJunior The book's proof uses $x_1^k$ instead of $|x_1|^k$. Does that mean $k \in \{1, 2, 3, \dots\}$? The proof is easy when $|x|^{\gamma} \in C^\infty$ because then $|x|^\gamma \phi \in C_c^{\infty}$.  I guess this is when $\gamma \in \{2, 4, 6, \dots\}$. The book's proof doesn't make sense if $|x|^{\gamma}$ isn't smooth because then $|x|^{\gamma}\partial_{y_j}u$ doesn't make sense as a distribution since we only know $\partial_{y_j}u$ is a distribution, not a function.

Comment: The book does not make it clear if $k \in \{1,2,3,..\}$ or $k \in \mathbb{R}^+$. But I agree with your argument.

Comment: In the book is just written $k \geq 0$.